# Laravel - Asignar un value en un option de un select!

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hola (estoy recien aprendiendo),

Necesito en el value asignar el valor del id. Ejemplo: `<option value="{{$idcategoriacuenta}}">{{$categoria}}</option>`

El problema es en el **array()** no se como mandar el valor de la *categoria* y el *idcategoriacuenta*

Tengo el siguiente código:

En el **Modelo**:

```
class Cuentasconcategoria extends Model
{
protected $table='view_cuentasconcategoria';
public $timestamps=false;
protected $fillable =[
  'idcategoriacuenta',
  'cuenta',
  'categoria',
];
}
```

En el **controlador**

```
public function create(){
 $categoriacuenta=Cuentasconcategoria::all();
 $attributes = array();
 foreach ( $categoriacuenta as $v ) {
    if ( !isset($attributes[$v->cuenta]) ) {
        $attributes[$v->cuenta] = array();
    }
    $attributes[$v->cuenta][$v->categoria] = $v->categoria;
 }
return view ('inventario.articulo.create',
["attributes"=>$attributes]);
}
```

En la **vista:**

```
<select>
  @foreach ( $attributes as $key => $cuenta)
  <optgroup label="{{$key}}">
    @foreach ( $cuenta as $categoria )
        <option value="{{$categoria}}">{{$categoria}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </optgroup>
  @endforeach
    </select>
```

**Si funciona el código anterior** solo me falta asignar el value con el id

El resultado de lo anterior:
[image: Select funcionando]

Comment: Me base en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188712/laravel-populate-select-optgroup-dropdown-which-groups-records-by-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$categoriacuenta=Cuentasconcategoria::all();

luego en el foreach de la vista 

@foreach($categoriacuenta as $categoriacuenta)

 <option value="{{$categoriacuenta->idcategoriacuenta}}">{{$categoriacuenta->categoria}}</option>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Para que la respuesta sea más útil, deberías explicar de qué manera tu propuesta puede resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tu modelo y controlador están bien, la mofidicación lo requiere la vista y es lógico ya que la vista es la responsable de todo lo relacionado con la interfaz (el cómo mostrar al cliente).

Haz la siguiente modificación:

```
<select>
  @foreach ( $attributes as $key => $cuenta)
  <optgroup label="{{$key}}">
    @foreach ( $cuenta as $categoria )
        <option value="{{$categoria->idcategoriacuenta}}">{{$categoria}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </optgroup>
  @endforeach
    </select>
```

Esto es así porque el elemento  tiene el atributo "value" que corresponde al valor que tomará el select, mientras que su nodo hijo es lo que se mostrará visualmente.

A veces un  puede tener su value y su nodo hijo el mismo valor, pero por lo común serán diferentes.

```
<option value="{{$categoria->idcategoriacuenta}}">{{$categoria}}</option>
```

El primer valor será numérico y el segundo una cadena. Así puedes cambiar los valores que quieras mostrar de tu objeto $categoria según tus necesidades.